# Adding Favicon to my website

Tags: joomla

I am new to joomla and i am using joomla 1.5 and template rhuk_milkway to develop my website. I want to insert a Favicon by inserting the following piece of code in index.php and the favicon.ico in the /rhuk_milkway directory. but when i refresh the page the Favicon is not displaying. it displays the internet explorer favicon.I try to clear the cache in my browser but it can't work.

```
<link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

can any one help me fixing this.

Answer (score 1):

it should be like

```
<link href="templates/rhuk_milkyway/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

path of your template directory or where your favicon is place

Also Try it on Another browser from which you have not accessed your site earlier

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your template have this tag `<jdoc:include type="head" />` after head tag than joomla will automatically add

```
<link href="templates/rhuk_milkyway/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

and replace current favicon icon with your one.
Clear the cache and try.

Answer (score 0):

put your favicon.ico in this path:

```
JOOMLAROOT/templates/rhuk_milkway
```

and then open templateDetails.xml in this folder, and write this code betwwen this tag :

```
<file>
<filename>favicon.ico</filename>
....
</file>
```

you don't need put `<link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />` in the head. just place this code in your head: `<jdoc:include type="head" />`
joomla does it itself!